# JSON Get Element When It's a Date?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to use a GET request and manipulate some JSON.  However, the results include a date in the JSON.  Would do I work through this - I can select the information before but can't select the data within the date. I've tried "2018-06-28" to no avail.

```
"element_count" : 8,
  "near_earth_objects" : {
    "2018-06-28" : [ {
      "links" : {
        "self" : "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3251512?api_key=OFC1FIb06lwdyot0ZN3yRQAQe8pvhK0R1wCx5GAu"
      },
      "neo_reference_id" : "3251512",
      "name" : "(2004 RX10)",
      "nasa_jpl_url" : "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3251512",
      "absolute_magnitude_h" : 21.3,
      "estimated_diameter" : {
        "kilometers" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 0.1460679643,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 0.3266178974
        },
        "meters" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 146.0679642714,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 326.6178974458
        },
        "miles" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 0.090762397,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 0.2029508896
        },
        "feet" : {
          "estimated_diameter_min" : 479.2256199,
          "estimated_diameter_max" : 1071.581062656
        }
      },
      "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid" : false,
      "close_approach_data" : [ {
        "close_approach_date" : "2018-06-28",
        "epoch_date_close_approach" : 1530169200000,
        "relative_velocity" : {
          "kilometers_per_second" : "13.0790754914",
          "kilometers_per_hour" : "47084.6717691282",
          "miles_per_hour" : "29256.5839667675"
        },
        "miss_distance" : {
          "astronomical" : "0.1504186394",
          "lunar" : "58.5128517151",
          "kilometers" : "22502308",
          "miles" : "13982286"
        },
        "orbiting_body" : "Earth"
      } ]
    },
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
jQuery.getJSON("neo-current.json", function(data) {  
    $("#neo").html(data.element_count+" NEO(s)");
    var date = "2018-06-28";
    $.each(data, function(index, i) {
        console.log(i.near_earth_objects.date.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

`console.log(i.near_earth_objects[date].name);`

Comment: Unfortunately, that results in: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2018-06-28' of undefined."

Comment: Mean your loop/iteration is failed somewhere, It looks like the `i.near_earth_objects` is undefined. Try narrowing down the root cause by inspecting the value of `i.near_earth_objects` & even `i` within your loop.

Comment: I can get it to work with:

$.each(data.near_earth_objects["2018-06-28"], function(index, i) {
 console.log(i.name);
});

But, trying to get it to automatically set the date from the JSON - i.e. data.near_earth_objects[1] or something like that. So I don't have to use moment and add another dependency.

Comment: If so, you can use `for ... in` as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in . ex: `for (let date in i.near_earth_objects)`. Do aware of the order, it's a loop through Object's keys, it's not supposed to maintain the order as you see from the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var hazardous = '0';
    jQuery.getJSON("neo-current.json", function(data) {  
        $("#neo").html(data.element_count+" NEO(s)");
        var date = Object.keys(data.near_earth_objects)[0];
        $.each(data.near_earth_objects[date], function(index, i) {
            console.log(i.name+" "+i.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid);
            if (i.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid == true) {
                hazardous ++
            } else {
                //Do Nothing
            }
        });
        $("#hazardous-neo").html(hazardous+" NEO(S)");
    });
});
```